# Removing backslashes in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, backslash

To preface, I have already looked at several similar posts about this issue, and none of them have a solution that I can see.

I am trying to remove backslashes from a large text. This is my cleaning code so far:

```
rawData = open("full_LOTR_1.txt").read()
cleaning1 = rawData.replace("\x92", "")
cleaning2 = cleaning1.replace("\n", "")
cleaning3 = cleaning2.replace("\\", "")
```

The third cleaning has been proposed already in several posts, and while it may have worked for them, I can not see it work for me. There are still backslashes in the string before the ' character.

Keep in mind I am very much a beginner.

Comment: Check that you are effectively looking the value of `cleaning3` and not another of your variables

Comment: do`print()` it ... the backslashes are most probably only pythons way to tell you that there are _literal_ `'` inside a string ... the backslashes are just escapecharacters so you can see that `'Doc\'s Horse'` contains a `'`

Comment: Thank you @PatrickArtner, that was indeed the case. :)